# Why my own Tooltip in jQuery doesn't hide after the second click on the input field?

Tags: jquery, html, css, tooltip, hide

I have two input fields an an Span tag what is display="none";. if i click in one of this two inputs, i would like to show my tooltip. jQuery show my tooltip and if i enter a key hide this.
That works, too.

1. If i click again in the same input, jquery show me the span, but doesn't hide this again after enter a key. Why?
2. Why my tooltip ist not on the middle of the input field?

**CSS**

```
.arrow_box {
   position: absolute;
   background-color: #ffdc00;
   background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #ffdc00, #e3c300);
   -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
   -moz-transform: translate(0, -50%);
   -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);    
   transform: translate(0, -50%); 
   top: 50%;
   vertical-align: middle;
   display: block;
   width: 200px;
   right: -80px;  
   padding: 5px 15px;
}

.arrow_box p {
   padding: 0;
}

.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
   right: 100%;
   top: 50%;
   border: solid transparent;
   content: " ";
   height: 0;
   width: 0;
   position: absolute;
   pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box:after {
   border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
   border-right-color: #ffdc00;
   border-width: 10px;
   margin-top: -10px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
   /*border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);*/
   /*border-right-color: #c2e1f5;*/
   border-width: 36px;
   margin-top: -36px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" name="name" maxlength="100" value="" class="form-control tooltip" id="password">
<span class="tool-tip right slideIn" style="display: none;">
    <div class="arrow_box">
        <b>Tooltip</b>
        <p>Test 11 22 333</p>
    </div>
</span>
</div> 
<br/>
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" name="name" maxlength="100" value="" class="form-control tooltip" id="password">
<span class="tool-tip right slideIn" style="display: none;">
    <div class="arrow_box">
        <b>Tooltip 2</b>
        <p>mTest test tes steste</p>
    </div>
</span>
</div>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        // ToolTip
        jQuery('.tooltip').focus(function() {
            // $( this ).next( "span" ).css( "display", "block" );
            $this = jQuery(this);

            jQuery( this ).next( "span" ).show("slow");

            jQuery('.tooltip').keyup(function() { 
                jQuery( this ).next( "span" ).hide('slow');
            });
        });
});
```

MY EXAMPLE:

https://jsfiddle.net/2pt8nqcx/

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any focusout and your next("span") is useless.. next is already your span :)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        // ToolTip
        $('.tooltip').focus(function() {
            $this = $(this);
            $this.next().show("slow");

        });

        $('.tooltip').focusout(function(){
            $this = jQuery(this);
            $this.next().hide();
        })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('.tooltip').focusin(function() {     
                jQuery( this ).next( "span" ).show("slow");
            }).focusout(function() { 
                jQuery( this ).next( "span" ).hide();
            });;
 });
```

This also works, if using keyup was your intended:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('.tooltip').focus(function() {
                jQuery( this ).next( "span" ).show("slow");
                jQuery('.tooltip').keyup(function() { 
                    jQuery( this ).next( "span" ).hide();
                });
            });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) parameters in hide is supported in jquery version 1.9 and later. Also, you need to hide the tooltip on focusout. See below code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

            // ToolTip
            jQuery('.tooltip').focus(function() {
                // $( this ).next( "span" ).css( "display", "block" );
                $this = jQuery(this);

                jQuery( this ).next( "span" ).show("slow");
            });
            jQuery('.tooltip').focusout(function() {
                    jQuery( this ).next( "span" ).hide("slow");
            });
 });

2.) In your jsfiddle, you are applying css to arrow_box class. You need to apply position to its parent first. Add below css and you need to make few more changes in right/transform value and you are good.

.tool-tip {
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks for the help. 
I have one another question. Can i have "onfocus" hide and "keyup" hide together?

And if i was in the first input an press TAB the tooltip doesn't showed in the secend input.

Comment: Thanks, but if i press TAB i see the tooltip and directly hide this. Actually, i should after press kex this.

Answer (score 0):

I have still a problem. If i press TAB the tooltip doesn't showed in the seceond input.

I must use jQuery 1.7.2.

**JQUERY**:

```
jQuery('.tooltip').focus(function() {
            jQuery( this ).next( "span" ).show("slow");

            jQuery('.tooltip').keyup(function() { 
                jQuery( this ).next( "span" ).hide();
            });
});

jQuery('.tooltip').focusout(function() { 
            jQuery( this ).next( "span" ).hide();
});
```

**EXAMPLE:**

https://jsfiddle.net/2pt8nqcx/19/